# Setting up the group permissions in samba throughout archlinux

Tags: permissions, samba, user-groups

I wanted to set up the permissions for the group on linux, so members can access the group on windows.
I coded it in archlinux and it looks like this :

```
[test]
  path = /srv/smbtest/test
  valid users = @fibu
  read list = @fibu
  write list = @fibu
  public = no
  available = yes
  guest ok = no
  browseable = yes
  create mask = 0664
  directory mask = 0775
  force group = fibu
  force user = manoca
```

Previously, two test users were added to group fibu to check if it works or not.
When I try to login on windows in folder test with credentials that I set up for these two test members that I added, I get the upcoming error message:

```
\\datastorevm\test is not accesible. You might not have a permission to use this network resource. Contact the administrator of this server to find out if you have access permissions. 

Multiple connections to a server or shared resource by the same user, using more than one user name is not allowed. Disconnect all previous connections to the server or shared resource and try again.
```

Did anyone encounter similar problem? How to solve it?

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it, smbpasswd was necessarry to be defined for all the existing users in a given group. After that samba login functioned perfectly. Conduct the following command using root privileges:

- `smbpasswd -a groupname username` (username from member of privileged group)
- *Define and retype new password*
- Restart service with `rc-service smb restart`

Login to the encrypted folder is now possible on windows with valid credentials

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you were able to establish at least a partial connection to the samba share, then attempted to connect again using different credentials?

Windows only allows one set of credentials [per share name](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/troubleshoot/windows-server/networking/cannot-connect-to-network-share). You may be able to just run `net use \\datastorevm\test /DELETE` in windows, or you may have to restart the `LanmanWorkstation` service to get it to reset. Then you should be able to access the share with a new user if there are no other issues.

More info in the answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24933661/